# NTAG213 Not being picked up by the RC522 Module

Tags: arduino, nfc, nxp, mfrc522

I have been using the RC522 module to read and write things to the tags it came with. But when I tried to use an NTAG213 I bought for a recent project it will act as if it isn't there. I've tried a lot of different code to try to get it to recognize it but I haven't had any success.

I’ve mostly been trying to use the module that the RC522 needs on the arduino UNO

Have I just not been using the right code? Or is it not possible for the RC522 to recognize the tag?

Ok I was just able to scan the tag using a friend’s phone and I have found the manufacturer and the protocol. The manufacturer is NXP and it uses the ISO/IEC 14443-3 protocol
'''c++

```
    #include <SPI.h>
    #include <MFRC522.h>

    #define RST_PIN         9          // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
    #define SS_PIN          10         // Configurable, see typical pin layout above

    MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);  // Create MFRC522 instance

    void setup() {
        Serial.begin(9600);     // Initialize serial communications with the PC
        while (!Serial);        // Do nothing if no serial port is opened (added for Arduinos based on ATMEGA32U4)
        SPI.begin();            // Init SPI bus
        mfrc522.PCD_Init();     // Init MFRC522
        mfrc522.PCD_DumpVersionToSerial();  // Show details of PCD - MFRC522 Card Reader details
        Serial.println(F("Scan PICC to see UID, SAK, type, and data blocks..."));
    }

    void loop() {
        // Reset the loop if no new card present on the sensor/reader. This saves the entire process when idle.
        if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
            return;
        }

        // Select one of the cards
        if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
            return;
        }

        // Dump debug info about the card; PICC_HaltA() is automatically called
        mfrc522.PICC_DumpToSerial(&(mfrc522.uid));
    }
```

'''

Comment: How do you communicate with the RC522? Are you using a library or do you accessing the registers all on your own?
And could you please show us your code that do not work.

Comment: @theSealion I am communicating with the RC522 by plugging it into the arduino that is plugged into my computer. Other chips Are working and i've updated the question with the code

Comment: Which version (number) of the rfid library do you use?
Do you see any output on the serial interface?

Comment: @theSealion I just learned that I need to turn the RC522 to the ISO 14443A/MIFARE mode. But I have no idea how to do that. I have the MFRC522 Library by the Github community Version 1.4.4

Answer (score 1):

You don't tell us which code (or library you are using) but the most common arduino library has some "special" methods to communicate with MIFARE ULTRALIGHT chip (and most of the examples ignore the Ultralight Chips)

Try the NTAG216 Example, if you are using the "miguelbalboa" library.

Comment: I have updated it with more information